# AppFlood Splas Screen In Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads

I create a game by Unity3D, I'm using AppFlood ads to show banners.

But for AppFlood new Splash Screen SDK there is no unity SDK

Is there any way to use this ads in my game?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question on AppFlood Splash Screen.

At this point we can't support Unity3D projects for the Splash Screen SDK. We will work on the plugin in the future but it's hard to say when it will be available. If you still want to use the SDK, you can try and create an adapter yourself, but this may require more advanced programming skills.

You can send me an email at weronika@papayamobile.com and I will remember to let you know when the official Unity plugin comes out.